# Importing d3.js in angular 2 project not working

Tags: d3.js, angular, asp.net-core

Trying to use d3.js in my project but getting error "Cannot find module d3" when importing it like this

`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
....
"d3" :  "4.1.1"
```

},

systemjs.config.js

```
 var map = {
    'app': 'appScripts', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'libs/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'd3' : 'libs/d3'
};
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }, ...
    'd3': { main: 'd3.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } };
```

My d3.js is in right folder.

[image: d3.js file]

Note that all other libraries are working except that one. Also I tried to do npm install d3 along with fixing directives and it wasnt working as well.
If it matters Im using asp.net core project for building angular app.

Comment: Is the ds3 folder also inside your `node_modules` folder? This is where npm stores them by default and you usually copy it to wwwroot/libs afterwards (i.e. via gulp task). If that doesnt help did you try installing a type definition (using typings or tsd)? It's available at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts so you probably can install it via `typings install dt~d3 --global --save` once you have typings installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include d3.js with `<script>` tag and install appropriate typings then you should be able to use d3 without imports.

Comment: I did that in the end, not the solution I wanted but it works.

Comment: what is the purpose of installing the typings if you don't import d3 in your typescript?

Comment: You still need typings if you use library from typescript.